# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence giving error for FOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, for-loop

I am getting the following error:

> ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence while running a loop inside a PL SQL
>   block.

The syntax tye for FOR LOOP I am using is - for .. loop
or it looks like

```
for cur in <cursor query>
loop
   do some processing..
end loop;
```

I have already explored internet for possible causes of the problem, so just to exclude all possibilities.

1. Loop does not use any 'for update' statement.
2. There is no chance I'm trying to fetch next row after all rows have been
   fetched, because the syntax for .. loop handles this itself.
3. There is one row which will be fetched through cursor query for my
   scenario and it's very well processing that row.

I have written and implemented similar code a thousand of times and never had this problem.

Comment: It's very hard to answer without the actual code.

Comment: Can you please share where and how you use your sequence that may cause the error? + specify your oracle version(`select * from v$version`)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and complete stack trace.

Comment: Is there a `commit` in the code you are not showing us?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it's not allowed for me to write actual code here. Also the code contains a thousand of lines including SQL statements and many subprogram calls.

Comment: @Chriz Sorry didn't get you. We are not using any sequence here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How does it matter to have a commit in the code. It's not for update clause in cursor definition.

Comment: Yes it matters because a commit will close the implicit cursor opened by the for loop

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name No it doesn't. A similar code I have written  and tested.
SQL> SELECT * FROM ADA_JOIN_TEMP;

       RNC        RDC
---------- ----------
         3         41
         2         41

SQL> 
SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR CUR IN (SELECT RN FROM ADA_TEMP WHERE RN < 4) LOOP
  3  
  4      UPDATE ADA_JOIN_TEMP SET RDC = RDC+10 WHERE RNC = CUR.RN;
  5  
  6      COMMIT;
  7  
  8    END LOOP;
  9  
 10  END;
 11  /


SQL> SELECT * FROM ADA_JOIN_TEMP;

       RNC        RDC
---------- ----------
         3         71
         2         71

Comment: Try to disable autocommit (if it's on) on the client and see if that helps.

Comment: @dsp_user I checked. It's disabled only. Also I tried running procedure in debug mode, still it giving same error

Comment: I assume you've already restarted your database and the client. You may also  try another client to make sure the problem is not on the client side.

Comment: No there was no case of database or client restart. I tried in different sessions as well, but same problem.